# Wordpress Sorting through URL

Tags: wordpress

```
$p_args = array(
    "post_type" => "post",
    "v_sortby" => "date",
    "numberposts" => 10,
    "showposts" => 10,
    "posts_per_page" => 10
    );
```

I can sort this through URL like

```
www.example.com/?post_type=post&v_sortby=date&numberposts=10&showposts=10
```

Then How Could I write these into URL form?

```
$args = array(
        "post_type" => "post",
        "meta_query" => array (
            array (
              "key" => "quality",
              "value" => "hd",
              "compare" => "IN"
            )
          ) 
    );
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you try rewording to be more clear.

Comment: I am sorting my posts in post page template file in my wordpress by using arguments... How can I sort posts using URL parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used http_build_query() to generate url for the following parameters

```
<?php
$args = array(
        "post_type" => "post",
        "meta_query" => array (
            array (
              "key" => "quality",
              "value" => "hd",
              "compare" => "IN"
            )
          ) 
    );

echo http_build_query($args);
?>
```

which echoed url query on my page.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass those query arguments in the url?

[`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

or are you trying to get the values from the url?

[`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)